# How to replace a div content upon clicking a bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried using JavaScript without successes because I don't know how to connect my bottom (hyperlink in reality) to the div content itself so I would just replace the string of my buttom instead of the div itself.
The image is the best explanation:
https://ibb.co/xz0S8sm

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="schedule-left">
                <ul class="shedule-navigation">
                    <li class="schedule-list"><a id="schedule-color" class="schedule-b" href="#"><i id="sch" class="far fa-clock"></i>Schedule</a></li>
                    <li class="schedule-list"><a id="schedule-color-b" class="schedule-b" href="#"><i id="sch" class="fas fa-list"></i>Tracking</a></li>
                    <li class="schedule-list"><a id="schedule-color-b" class="schedule-b" href="#"><i id="sch" class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Organize</a></li>
                </ul>
            <div id="schedule-tasks">
                <p><strong>Schedule tasks</strong> to keep track of their completion. Sync provides  <br> multiple scheduling options including alarms and reminders.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>You can always add new tasks or change the settings of existing <br> ones in your calendar view or the app control panel</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>It's easy to stay focused on your most important daily activities <br> that will get you closer to meeting your goals</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Use phone reminders to free up your long term memory which <br> will reduce stress and make you more productive</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="lightbox">
                    <a class="butoon-lightbox" href="#">Terms</a>
                    <a id="privacy" class="butoon-lightbox" href="#">Privacy</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="tracking-tasks" style="display:none;">
                <p><strong>Keep track of everything</strong> and analyse your progress while using the app. In less than a month you should be seeing improved results when it comes to time management and task prioritization</p>
                <p><strong>Anyone can enjoy the app</strong> matter their gender, age, occupation or location in the world. Sync's algorithms have been built to be flexible and functional for any person in the world</p>
                <p><strong>Achieve the impossible</strong> just by carefully monitoring your progress and keeping the app updated with daily operations. It's easier than you think and it only takes a couple of minutes</p>
                <a href="#">Terms & Conditions >></a>
            </div>
            <div id="organize-tasks" style="display:none;">
                <p><strong>Use the power of social interactivity</strong> to keep you motivated and focused on your daily and long term goals. It's revolutionary.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Commiting to something in front of a crowd gives you little room to walk back on your promise and makes you push on</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>No more frustrations of loosing focus and not being efficient. Sync main purpose is to solve just that and make you happy</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>It's the first mobile app that can turn you in a better organized person without the pressure of failing like other systems</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Recognized by a lot of trainers and life coaches Sync is the number one tool they recommend time management</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="shedule-right">
                <img class="december" src="images/description-2-app.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: question doesn't make any sense.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DCR [link](https://ibb.co/xz0S8sm) Here's an image.

Comment: @Archon, so you want to change the content in the bottom when user click the tracking, schelude bottom, is that right?

Comment: @James Yes, that's right

Comment: @Archon, just post an answer, check if it works. I change the `a` to `button` since in your image, it is more likely a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you two ways to do it, by either using `display:none` and `display:revert` to switch as you are trying to do in your code, or use just have 1 div and directly writing using Javascript.

Using `display:none` and `display:revert`:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
buttons[0].onclick  =function(){
document.querySelector('#schedule-tasks').style.display ='revert'
document.querySelector('#tracking-tasks').style.display ='none'
document.querySelector('#organize-tasks').style.display = 'none'
}
buttons[1].onclick = function(){
document.querySelector('#schedule-tasks').style.display ='none'
document.querySelector('#tracking-tasks').style.display ='revert'
document.querySelector('#organize-tasks').style.display = 'none'
}
buttons[2].onclick = function(){
document.querySelector('#schedule-tasks').style.display ='none'
document.querySelector('#tracking-tasks').style.display ='none'
document.querySelector('#organize-tasks').style.display = 'revert'
}
```

```html
<div class="schedule-left">
                <ul class="shedule-navigation">
                    <li class="schedule-list"><button id="schedule-color-b" class="schedule-b" ><i id="sch" class="far fa-clock"></i>Schedule</li>
                    <li class="schedule-list"><button id="schedule-color-b" class="schedule-b" ><i id="sch" class="fas fa-list"></i>Tracking</li>
                    <li class="schedule-list"><button id="schedule-color-b" class="schedule-b" ><i id="sch" class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Organize</li>
                </ul>
            <div id="schedule-tasks">
                <p><strong>Schedule tasks</strong> to keep track of their completion. Sync provides  <br> multiple scheduling options including alarms and reminders.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>You can always add new tasks or change the settings of existing <br> ones in your calendar view or the app control panel</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>It's easy to stay focused on your most important daily activities <br> that will get you closer to meeting your goals</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Use phone reminders to free up your long term memory which <br> will reduce stress and make you more productive</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="lightbox">
                    <a class="butoon-lightbox" href="#">Terms</a>
                    <a id="privacy" class="butoon-lightbox" href="#">Privacy</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            
            
            
            <div id="tracking-tasks" style="display:none;">
                <p><strong>Keep track of everything</strong> and analyse your progress while using the app. In less than a month you should be seeing improved results when it comes to time management and task prioritization</p>
                <p><strong>Anyone can enjoy the app</strong> matter their gender, age, occupation or location in the world. Sync's algorithms have been built to be flexible and functional for any person in the world</p>
                <p><strong>Achieve the impossible</strong> just by carefully monitoring your progress and keeping the app updated with daily operations. It's easier than you think and it only takes a couple of minutes</p>
                <a href="#">Terms & Conditions >></a>
            </div>
            
            
            
            
            <div id="organize-tasks" style="display:none;">
                <p><strong>Use the power of social interactivity</strong> to keep you motivated and focused on your daily and long term goals. It's revolutionary.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Commiting to something in front of a crowd gives you little room to walk back on your promise and makes you push on</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>No more frustrations of loosing focus and not being efficient. Sync main purpose is to solve just that and make you happy</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>It's the first mobile app that can turn you in a better organized person without the pressure of failing like other systems</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Recognized by a lot of trainers and life coaches Sync is the number one tool they recommend time management</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            
            
            <div class="shedule-right">
                <img class="december" src="images/description-2-app.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Directly writing using Javascript

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
let content = document.querySelector('#content')
buttons[0].onclick= function(){content1()};
buttons[1].onclick= function(){content2()};
buttons[2].onclick= function() {content3()};
//make the initial value to be schedule-tasks
window.onload = content1()
function content1(){
content.innerHTML  = `
<div id="schedule-tasks">
<p><strong>Schedule tasks</strong> to keep track of their completion. Sync provides  <br> multiple scheduling options including alarms and reminders.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>You can always add new tasks or change the settings of existing <br> ones in your calendar view or the app control panel</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>It's easy to stay focused on your most important daily activities <br> that will get you closer to meeting your goals</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Use phone reminders to free up your long term memory which <br> will reduce stress and make you more productive</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="lightbox">
                    <a class="butoon-lightbox" href="#">Terms</a>
                    <a id="privacy" class="butoon-lightbox" href="#">Privacy</a>
                </ul>
                </div>`
}
function content2(){
content.innerHTML= `
 <div id="tracking-tasks" >
                <p><strong>Keep track of everything</strong> and analyse your progress while using the app. In less than a month you should be seeing improved results when it comes to time management and task prioritization</p>
                <p><strong>Anyone can enjoy the app</strong> matter their gender, age, occupation or location in the world. Sync's algorithms have been built to be flexible and functional for any person in the world</p>
                <p><strong>Achieve the impossible</strong> just by carefully monitoring your progress and keeping the app updated with daily operations. It's easier than you think and it only takes a couple of minutes</p>
                <a href="#">Terms & Conditions >></a>
            </div>
`
}
function content3(){
content.innerHTML=`   <div id="organize-tasks" >
                <p><strong>Use the power of social interactivity</strong> to keep you motivated and focused on your daily and long term goals. It's revolutionary.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Commiting to something in front of a crowd gives you little room to walk back on your promise and makes you push on</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>No more frustrations of loosing focus and not being efficient. Sync main purpose is to solve just that and make you happy</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>It's the first mobile app that can turn you in a better organized person without the pressure of failing like other systems</li>
                    <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Recognized by a lot of trainers and life coaches Sync is the number one tool they recommend time management</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            `
           }
```

```html
<div class="schedule-left">
                <ul class="shedule-navigation">
                    <li class="schedule-list"><button id="schedule-color-b" class="schedule-b" ><i id="sch" class="far fa-clock"></i>Schedule</li>
                    <li class="schedule-list"><button id="schedule-color-b" class="schedule-b" ><i id="sch" class="fas fa-list"></i>Tracking</li>
                    <li class="schedule-list"><button id="schedule-color-b" class="schedule-b" ><i id="sch" class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Organize</li>
                </ul>
<div id='content'></div>
            
            
            <div class="shedule-right">
                <img class="december" src="images/description-2-app.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, both versions work but the second version messes up my flex aliment. The image on my right goes down for some reason. I will try to figure it out tomorrow as to why. The first version works just fine. Thank you again.

Comment: @Archon, no problem. Glad I could help, if you can't figure it out tomorrow, you could tell me and I could help you:)

Comment: I was missing a closing </div> element. I figured it out after looking at the code for 3 hours haha.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `id` of the content upon click of the desired bottom to JavaScript function using `onclick` event, and make that `div` style visible. After this, you can hide the visibility of other contents. Here's the working:

```js
function changeContent(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  if (id != 'schedule-tasks')
    document.getElementById('schedule-tasks').style.display = 'none';
  if (id != 'tracking-tasks')
    document.getElementById('tracking-tasks').style.display = 'none';
  if (id != 'organize-tasks')
    document.getElementById('organize-tasks').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="schedule-left">
  <ul class="shedule-navigation">
    <li class="schedule-list"><a id="schedule-color" onclick="changeContent('schedule-tasks')" class="schedule-b" href="#"><i id="sch" class="far fa-clock"></i>Schedule</a></li>
    <li class="schedule-list"><a id="schedule-color-b" onclick="changeContent('tracking-tasks')" class="schedule-b" href="#"><i id="sch" class="fas fa-list"></i>Tracking</a></li>
    <li class="schedule-list"><a id="schedule-color-b" onclick="changeContent('organize-tasks')" class="schedule-b" href="#"><i id="sch" class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>Organize</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="schedule-tasks">
    <p><strong>Schedule tasks</strong> to keep track of their completion. Sync provides <br> multiple scheduling options including alarms and reminders.</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>You can always add new tasks or change the settings of existing <br> ones in your calendar view or the app control panel</li>
      <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>It's easy to stay focused on your most important daily activities <br> that will get you closer to meeting your goals</li>
      <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Use phone reminders to free up your long term memory which <br> will reduce stress and make you more productive</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="lightbox">
      <a class="butoon-lightbox" href="#">Terms</a>
      <a id="privacy" class="butoon-lightbox" href="#">Privacy</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="tracking-tasks" style="display:none;">
    <p><strong>Keep track of everything</strong> and analyse your progress while using the app. In less than a month you should be seeing improved results when it comes to time management and task prioritization</p>
    <p><strong>Anyone can enjoy the app</strong> matter their gender, age, occupation or location in the world. Sync's algorithms have been built to be flexible and functional for any person in the world</p>
    <p><strong>Achieve the impossible</strong> just by carefully monitoring your progress and keeping the app updated with daily operations. It's easier than you think and it only takes a couple of minutes</p>
    <a href="#">Terms & Conditions >></a>
  </div>
  <div id="organize-tasks" style="display:none;">
    <p><strong>Use the power of social interactivity</strong> to keep you motivated and focused on your daily and long term goals. It's revolutionary.</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Commiting to something in front of a crowd gives you little room to walk back on your promise and makes you push on</li>
      <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>No more frustrations of loosing focus and not being efficient. Sync main purpose is to solve just that and make you happy</li>
      <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>It's the first mobile app that can turn you in a better organized person without the pressure of failing like other systems</li>
      <li class="schedule-description"><i id="check-square" class="far fa-check-square"></i>Recognized by a lot of trainers and life coaches Sync is the number one tool they recommend time management</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="shedule-right">
  <img class="december" src="images/description-2-app.png" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.